# Angular2: How to send data from client to server when making request

Tags: angular, angular2-http

There is form and a button on client side, I want to send data that user typed in the form, to the server, where there is request handler that save data to the database, and from database to the client.

How can i do this I'm confused about the logic, I think there is use of body parser, also what is the role of headers, request option in that case, I found that solution but I'm not implementing blindly, I just want to do it my way after understanding

At the client side:

```
let headers: Headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let opts: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
opts.headers = headers;
this.http.post(
    'http://localhost:3000/addStudent',
    JSON.stringify(obj),
    opts
).subscribe((res: Response) => {
    console.log(res.json())
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.students = res.json();
    }, 3000)
})
```

At the server side:

```
app.post('/addStudent',function(req,res) {
var newStudent = new StudentModel(req.body);
console.log(req.body);
newStudent.save();
StudentModel.find(function(err,data) {
   if(err) res.send(err) 
   else res.json(data)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your question is related to `HTTP` i.e exchange of data from the client and server side both.
so doing same first you have to need to add `http` file in the `index.html` file like this:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

and you have to add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` whether at the tie of bootstrap or in the providers list.

so now come to `RequestOptions, Headers etc`. firstly import these as required from here...

```
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';
```

## Role of Header:

Basically Header is used to append `Content-Type` or some kind of confidential data like `username,Password` ,which we want to send to the server.
we have body part too which is also used to send data to server. for example:

```
this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
    this.headers.append("Authorization", 'confidential data or   
    something like that')
```

## RequestOptions :

Bascially `RequestOptions` is the collection of some properts like `method` (GET,POST,PUT....), `url or path to json file etc`, `Headers`
   `body part` and more. we can add different optipon as per need. for example here is the example of using `RequestOptions`.

```
this.requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
                method: RequestMethod.Post,
                url: "url path....",
                headers: this.headers,
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            });
```

here is some best tutorials i had found for the same. hope this may helps you.

@Pardeep.

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http

https://auth0.com/blog/2015/10/15/angular-2-series-part-3-using-http/

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/Request-class.html

Comment: can we still send the body stringified with GET? I tried HTTT get(url, options), but I could not get the body to reach the server, am I missing something?

Comment: No i don't think so that with GET request you can send body part. you can send body part with POST request as well as PUT request.

Comment: I guess it makes sense. but we come from a jQuery background, where we are literally spoiled by letting us pass a data json object in GET requests, it parametrizes them for us.